# Custom Post Type Archive Error, Takes Last Post as Title and Doesn't Work

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts

I have a cpt called **Videos** that suddenly doesn't work. In the archive page only appears the last video. The archive-title is not Videos anymore, it is Archive, while the browser title is the last (added) video title. ([Here's the URL](http://www.wildlionrecords.com/videos/)).

In the same website I have another CPT for Tours, and it is working fine with almost the same code ([here](http://www.wildlionrecords.com/tours/)).

I'm using an **archive-video.php** template file with the following code:

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

      <header class="seccion">
        <?php the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        <?php 
          if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' ) { 
            echo do_shortcode('[searchandfilter fields="av,tipodevideo" types=",checkbox" submit_label="Go" class="post_filters" all_items_labels="All" empty_search_url="http://www.wildlionrecords.com/en/videos/"]');
          }
          else {
            echo do_shortcode('[searchandfilter fields="av,tipodevideo" types=",checkbox" submit_label="Ir" class="post_filters" all_items_labels="Todos" empty_search_url="http://www.wildlionrecords.com/videos/"]');
          }
        ?>
      </header><!-- .page-header -->
    </div>
  </div><!-- #row -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<div class="container">

  <?php 
    $startRow = true;
    $postCounter = 0;
  ?>

  <?php

    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
  ?>

  <?php
    if ($startRow) {
      echo '<!-- START OF INTERNAL ROW --><div class="row">';
      $startRow = false;
    }  
  ?>
<?php
$postCounter += 1; 
?>
<!-- This div serves as the template for each post returned within the loop -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <article class="post blog-post">
    <div class="video-container"><?php the_field('url_del_video'); ?></div>
    <h3 class="titulo-video"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
  </article>
</div>
<?php 

if ( 3 === $postCounter ) {
  echo '</div><!-- END OF INTERNAL ROW -->';
  $startRow = true;
  $postCounter = 0;
}
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php 
if ($postCounter !== 0 ) {
  echo '</div><!-- END OF INTERNAL ROW -->';
}
?>
<?php else:  ?>
  <div class="page-header"><h1>Uh Oh!</h1></div>
  <p>Sorry, for some reason the contents of this page isn't displaying.</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
</div><!-- END OF ROW -->
</div><!-- END OF CONTAINER -->


</div><!--/.container-->  

<?php else : ?>

  <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Altogether with **pre_get_posts** from functions.php:

```
// ***************************
// ********   Pre get posts para videos

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_archive_videos' );
function custom_post_type_archive_videos( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'video' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'suppress_filters', true );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_tax_av' );
function custom_post_type_tax_av( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_tax( 'av' ) ) {
       $query->set( 'suppress_filters', true );
       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    }
}


add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_tax_tipodevideo' );
function custom_post_type_tax_tipodevideo( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_tax( 'tipodevideo' ) ) {
       $query->set( 'suppress_filters', true );
       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very heavy. In your shortcodes do you reset_query? The shortcode seems to be the malfunction.

Comment: I thought so, nevertheless I'm using it without problem in my other cpt.

Comment: Then again, `pre_get_posts` is too much, especially since you already have a template. Also you do not need to echo `do_shortcode` as that always echoes itself.

Comment: Try `return` rather than `echo` with the `do_shortcode`.

Comment: Post you shortcode functions and you will get a better answer.

Comment: The shortcode is from this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/, I really don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: disable all plugins and rule out any interference there. the body class on that page is `blog`, and everything else indicates that the main query "thinks" it's that single video page, not an archive, so something is completely borking the main query.

Comment: Sorry, i was meaning, where you have `do_shortcode` above, in the code. Use `return` before it rather than `echo`. I will take a look with a fresh face in a few hours.

Comment: Nevermind what I said. `do_shortcode` returns the results, it does NOT echo by default.

Comment: @NathanPowell I see many times that you post comments as answers and then delete them, as is in this case. This negatively reflects on your profile, and this adds up negative points which, if you have enough against you, you will be banned from posting answers. Only post real good quality answers. Take your time and read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related with a WordPress update and the permalinks, I simply updated the permalink structure (without modifying it) and everything worked fine.

I don't know why, but if you're facing the same problem or something similar is worth trying.